# ImportError: No module named theano

Tags: python, pip, theano

I use the introduction in the deeplearning tutorials.

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git
sudo pip install Theano
```

There is no problem with numpy and scipy.test:

```
python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"
python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"
```

but when i use the the theano test:

```
python -c "import theano; theano.test()"
```

It told me "no module named theano" which confused me a lot.

Comment: Obviously `theano` doesn't seem to be in the search path of your Python installation. Check out `sys.path` and verify that the module is located in one of the listed locations.

Comment: but when i run into python and import theano,it is also show the same error

Comment: I found there are python 2.7 and python 3.2 in the same computer. When i use python -V it print python 2.7,but the pip install all the module into the python 3.2 folder.

Comment: Try to use pip2 to install Theano, better use virtualenv or even better use virtualenvwrapper.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be certain of installing the version that will match your interpreter's and not pip's version of Python, you could try the following:

```
sudo -H python -m pip install Theano
```

Which would load the pip module corresponding to your interpreter.

If you're not a system administrator of your computer, or you just prefer to avoid installing python packages system-wide, you can do the following

```
pip install --user Theano
```

Third possibility would be to use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install Theano
```